# After importing a metric into Victoria Metrics, the metric is repeated for 5 minutes. What controls this behavior?

Tags: victoriametrics

I am writing some software that will be pushing data to Victoria Metrics, as below:

```
curl -d 'foo{bar="baz"} 30' -X POST 'http://[Victoria]/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/import/prometheus'
```

I noticed that if I push a single metric like this, it shows up as not a single data point but rather shows up repeatedly as if it was being scraped every 15 seconds, either until I push a new value for that metric or 5 minutes passes.

What setting/mechanism is causing this 5-minute repeat period?

Pushing data with a timestamp does not change this.  Metric gets repeated for 5 minutes after that time or until a change regardless.

I don't necessarily need to alter this behavior, just trying to understand why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

How do you query the database?
I guess this behaviour is due to the ranged query concept and ephemeral datapoints, check this out:

https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query

The interval between datapoints depends on the step parameter, which is 5 minutes when omitted.

If you want to receive only the real datapoints, go via export functions.

https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-export-time-series

Answer (score 0):

TSDB VM has ephemeral dots which fill gaps in the closest sample on the left to the requested timestamp.

So if you make the instant request:

```
curl "http://<victoria-metrics-addr>/api/v1/query?query=foo_bar&time=2022-05-10T10:03:00.000Z"
```

The time range at which VictoriaMetrics will try to locate a missing data sample is equal to 5m by default and can be overridden via step parameter.

step - optional max lookback window for searching for raw samples when executing the query. If step is skipped, then it is set to 5m (5 minutes) by default.

```
GET | POST /api/v1/query?query=...&time=...&step=...
```

You can read more about key concepts in this part of the documentation
[key-concepts](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#query-data)

There you can find also information about query range and different concepts about TSDB